# How do I do nested transactions in hibernate using only one connection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Context of problem I want to solve: I have a java spring http interceptor AuditHttpCommunicationInterceptor that audits communication with an external system. The HttpClieant that does the communication is used in a java service class that does some business logic called DoBusinessLogicSevice.
The DoBusinessLogicSevice opens a new transaction and using couple of collaborators does loads of stuff.

Problem to solove: Regardless of the outcome of any of the operations in DoBusinessLogicSevice (unexpected Exceptions, etc) I want audits to be stored in the database by AuditHttpCommunicationInterceptor.

Solution I used: The AuditHttpCommunicationInterceptor will open a new transaction this way:

```
    TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager, transactionDefinition).execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine. When a part of DoBusinessLogicSevice throws unexpected exception its transaction is rolled back, but the AuditHttpCommunicationInterceptor manages to store the audit in the database.

Problem that arises from this solution: AuditHttpCommunicationInterceptor uses a new db connection. So for every DoBusinessLogicSevice call I need 2 db connections.
Basicly, I want to know the solution to the problem: how to make TransactionTemplate "suspend" the current transaction and reuse the connection for a new one in this case.

Any ideas? :)

P.S.
One idea might be to take a different design approach: drop the interceptor and create an AuditingHttpClient that is used in DoBusinessLogicSevice  directly (not invoked by spring) but I cannot do that because I cannot access all http fields in there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the audit transaction is started after the business transaction has committed or rolled back. So why would it need a second connection? If I'm wrong, please try to explain the sequence of the operations.

Comment: If you would have two methods :

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
doAudit() 

@Transactional
doBusiness() {
....
....
doAudit();
}
it would have been two transactions and doAudit it would have been independent of the first one

Comment: @ JB Nizet: Those transactions are nested. The business transaction starts, does stuff, the http call is audited in a separate inner transaction by the interceptor which is commited, the business transaction does some more things and commits

Comment: @Cris: As far as I know there is no difference between annotation driven transactions and those that I pasted above. I just did what you described but without using annotations. The @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW will use a new DB Connection and I cannot afford that.

Comment: If you're using a connection pool the connection should be getting reused anyways.  Why go through all the trouble?  Spring doesn't support tying multiple transactions to the same db connection out of the box as far as I know.

Comment: @Pace: we have a constraint, the db connection pool size. We have loads of threads and if we introduce one new connection per thread this leads to doubling the connection count. So instead of a 100 we will have 200 for example, we cant afford that now.

Comment: Could you wait to open the transaction until after the doAudit() is finished and that way you still need two connections but they are serialized so that no thread ever has two at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring supports nested transactions (propagation="NESTED"), but this really depends on the database platform, and I don't believe every database platform is capable of handling nested transactions.

I really don't see what's a big deal with taking connection from a pool, doing a quick audit transaction and returning connection back.

**Update:** While Spring supports nested transactions, it looks like Hibernate doesn't. If that's the case, I say: go with another connection for audit.

Comment: We will use another connection and see how it goes.