# How to create a new Hibernate transaction without a new connection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

How do I modify this code so that is does not use a new db connection but reuses the current one (from the enclosing transaction)?

```
TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager, transactionDefinition).execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    @Override
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Related to [How do I do nested transactions in hibernate using only one connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930496/how-do-i-do-nested-transactions-in-hibernate-using-only-one-connection)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you probably cant. Unless you somehow succeed in using hibernate and the underlying database so that they support nested transactions. Many databases dont and I am not sure if hibernate does.  (since it requires a new transaction to be made)

Comment: Thanks Markus. The **new transaction is fine, thats what I want**. I just **don't want a new connection**.

Comment: the point is that since hibernate doesnt support nested transactions, you cant have a new transaction with out a new connection. So either change the REQUIRES_NEW to REQUIRES (?) or make a new connection and a new transaction.